# Why is my Keras CNN model reaching a local minima with so much data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am extremely new to machine learning. I have collected a labeled dataset of over 350,000 images that belong to 9 categories. I have been trying to create a CNN but have run into several roadblocks. The main one being after 1 epoch my models accuracy, validation loss and validation accuracy all remain unchanged in later epochs.

My main question is what am I doing wrong that is allowing my network to reach a local minima so quickly and what can I do to improve my model? I will include below some results and more information about of my model architecture. Any help is greatly appreciated!

- Training data is 60% of dataset
- Validation data is 20% of dataset
- Testing data is 20% of dataset

[image: Model training results]

```
IMAGE_SIZE = [225,300]
BATCH_SIZE = 32
NUM_EPOCHS = 10

class_weight = 
              [0: 1588.3125, 1: 457.434, 2: 83.53433162892622, 
               3: 13.31608057755007, 4: 1.9566857729489264, 5: 2.7059415077374473, 
               6: 2.6158218582734802, 7: 1.6870270110788204, 8: 18.367892707998713]

initial_learning_rate = 0.01
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate, decay_steps=20, decay_rate=0.96, staircase=True
)

checkpoint_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    f"model_weights.h5", save_best_only=True
)

early_stopping_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    patience=10, restore_best_weights=True
)

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(*IMAGE_SIZE,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (2,2), activation = tf.nn.relu))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (2,2), activation = tf.nn.relu))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (2,2), activation = tf.nn.relu))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(512, (2,2), activation = tf.nn.relu))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation = tf.nn.softmax))
model.add(layers.Dense(9))

model.compile(
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule), 
    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), 
    metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(
    train_dataset, 
    epochs = NUM_EPOCHS, 
    validation_data=(valid_dataset),
    callbacks=[checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb],
    class_weight=class_weight)
```

[image: Model Summary]

Comment: You don't know if it is local minima or not, you need softmax activation in the last layer or from_logits=True in the loss function. Also using softmax in your first dense layer is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Some activation functions are not purposefully chosen. (Have a look at https://machinelearningmastery.com/choose-an-activation-function-for-deep-learning/ for detailed information).

Since you are predicting class probabilities, you want the final dense layer (which contains 9 neurons) to produce a vector of values that can be interpreted as probabilities of class membership (i.e. they sum up to 1.0). For this, you can use the softmax function.

```
model.add(layers.Dense(9, activation = tf.nn.softmax))
```

For all other layer, you can use ReLU activation (also for the first dense layer).

```
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation = tf.nn.relu))
```